# Selecting columns when defining the relations to eager load on every query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

How can I select which columns to load when defining the relations to eager load on every query?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
class Partner extends Model
{
    protected $with = [
        'statistics',
        'event' => function($query)
        {
            $query->select(['id', 'name']);
        }
    ];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$with` is used to specify the relation that must be eager load on every query and not to specify the visible columns.
To specify the visible columns i.e. the columns which should be included in the query you can use `$visible`.

```
protected $visible = ['id','name'];
```

### Extra:

You can use `$hidden` to indicate laravel to hide the columns.
For example you want to hide the specific columns.

```
protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
```

Or, in your relation method you can use `Select()` method to define the columns that should be included in that specific relation.
`Select()` method accepts an array of fields to be selected. **And it is mandatory 
to include the key(column name) which defines the relation between the two tables.**
For example suppose you have two models A and B with one to one relationship, then you can do following.

```
public function A(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\B')->Select(['id','name']);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want to hide the other attributes for every query. This is specific for this eager load situation.

Comment: for eager loading `event` ?

Comment: Yes, on the `Partner` model only.

Comment: ok. did you tried this `$query->select(['id', 'name','partner_id']);` considering partner_id as a foreign key in events model.

Comment: in your current function only

Comment: as it is necessary to include key which defines relation

Comment: Doesn't work. The error I get is `syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120843/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-j).